# Is it possible to get the uvs for each face of the object applied in the urp shader?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

Is it possible to get the uvs for each face of the object applied in the urp shader?

Is it possible to determine the number of each face differently by tiling on the obtained face? I know it can be imported from other shaders other than urp, but urp can't work?

Answer (score 0):

UVs are given for the **vertices**. You can get the UV of a vertex like this:

```
// This shader draws a texture on the mesh.
Shader "Example/GetUV"
{
    Properties
    { 
        _BaseMap("Base Map", 2D) = "white"
    }

    SubShader
    {
        Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" "RenderPipeline" = "UniversalRenderPipeline" }

        Pass
        {
            HLSLPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/ShaderLibrary/Core.hlsl"            

            struct Attributes
            {
                float4 positionOS   : POSITION;
                // The uv variable contains the UV coordinate on the texture for the
                // given vertex.
                float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct Varyings
            {
                float4 positionHCS  : SV_POSITION;
                // The uv variable contains the UV coordinate on the texture for the
                // given vertex.
                float2 uv           : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            TEXTURE2D(_BaseMap);
            SAMPLER(sampler_BaseMap);

            CBUFFER_START(UnityPerMaterial)
                float4 _BaseMap_ST;
            CBUFFER_END

            Varyings vert(Attributes IN)
            {
                Varyings OUT;
                OUT.positionHCS = TransformObjectToHClip(IN.positionOS.xyz);
                OUT.uv = IN.uv;
                return OUT;
            }

            half4 frag(Varyings IN) : SV_Target
            {
                //here you can use your UV as IN.uv to get a pixel from a texture
                half4 color = SAMPLE_TEXTURE2D(_BaseMap, sampler_BaseMap, IN.uv);
                return color;
            }
            ENDHLSL
        }
    }
}
```

In shader graph, you can access the UV through the node called UV.

Answer (score 0):

Unity shaders have uvs and vertices, which can be used.
It seems to be done by first bringing the vertex range of each face from uv and tiling it with several.
Then divide it into a square shape by dividing its size and then adjust the texture position to make it.
https://docs.unity3d.com/2020.3/Documentation/Manual/shader-ReflectiveBumpedVertexLit.html